# Why can't I find skypeforlinux in some apt-cache search?

Tags: 14.04, apt, skype

I have seen that in some countries Skype for Linux is not available. They get redirected to old Skype or they get a message that they don't have access.

When I try to search it using:

```
apt-cache search skype
```

It doesn't return `skypeforlinux`, but it returns `skype` (the older version). When I search on my pc, it shows `skypeforlinux` and not `skype`. These two versions are not compatible for calling each other. So, I want to know how can I install Skype for Linux on my friend's computer who is in another country?

I sent the deb file for new `skype` but when he launches the `skypeforlinux`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks the latest version 8 worked not the 5th.

Answer (score -2):

Download skype for 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04+ from below link
https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/

And install .deb file using

## dpkg -i package name